# kubernates hostPath type check failed is not a file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-volume

## hostPath type check failed

i deploy my pod ,but something wrong .
i deploy daemmon  in my kubernates
[image]

two node is correct and woking ,but only one are pending . i describe this pod

error message said:
[image]

follow is my logstash.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: monitor-logtash
spec:
#  replicas: 1
 # minReadySeconds: 120
 # strategy: 
 #   type: RollingUpdate
 #   rollingUpdate:
 #     maxSurge: 1
 #     maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: monitor-logtash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: monitor-logtash
        version: v1
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets: 
        - name: dockerlogin
      containers:
      - name: monitor-logtash
        image: xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/logstash:7.11.2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts: 
          - name: log 
            mountPath: /data/log/
          - name: logstash-conf
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
          - name: logstash-yml
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
          - name: log4j-pattern
            mountPath: /data/config/patterns/log4j-pattern.conf
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9600
        - containerPort: 5044
      volumes: 
        - name: log
          hostPath: 
            path: /data/log/
            type: Directory
        - name: logstash-conf
          hostPath:
            path: /data/www/logstash/logstash.conf
            type: File
        - name: logstash-yml
          hostPath:
            path: /data/www/logstash/logstash.yml
            type: File
        - name: log4j-pattern
          hostPath:
            path: /data/www/logstash/log4j-pattern.conf
            type: File
```

### here is my config , and these file is defined existed on  each server

[image]

## resolved

### the answer is i created wrong file

Comment: I was getting the same error for another file and it turns out there was an error in the installation. Perhaps retry installing?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the actual error message you get?  `kubectl describe` should print out text output, not an image file.

Comment: You might consider pushing the configuration into the pods using a ConfigMap; that will be more reliable than trying to manually copy the files on to every single node in the cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze which log do you want to see ?

Answer (score 0):

Some file are missing from your host.

I advise you to use configmap and secret to store your configuration and be able to update them without going on the nodes